# Convert Excel array formula into PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, excel

I want to convert `{=(PRODUCT(1 + A2:A85) )}` into PHP or JavaScript. I've searched google for "array excel formulas", but I could not find right result. How do I convert `{=(PRODUCT(1 + A2:A85) )}`?
I have array for the `A2:A85` range. My array is like this:

```
var abc_array={2,3,4,5,67,7,8.........}.
```

Comment: Is `{=(PRODUCT(1 + A2:A85) )}`a valid formula on Excel?

Comment: How does the `1 +` work?  Does it add 1 to the product, or add 1 to each element within the array?  I don't have excel so I can't test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not tested but should work, im not the best at php so maybe someone could clean this up a little:

```
function product($array)
{
  $cons = $array[0];

    foreach($array as $num)
    {
        $cons = ($cons*$num);
    }

  return $cons;
}
```

Edit: just read @Eclecticist comment I missed the +1, but this shows as invalid if I try in Excel can you give some more info on what that does?

Comment: Hi Izion, thanks for answer, I don't know what is doing 1+. this is original formula  =(PRODUCT(1 + custom!A2:A85) ). custom is a sheet name. Maybe this will help you for answer.

Comment: @Ismail, Removing the +1 will pull the value from another sheet I just don't have enough knowledge with Excel to see what this does. I have checked the PRODUCT function docs but it does not shed any light on the matter.